# How to implement a planned load testing profile in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I collected analytics from the application and got a chart of its use during the day. I want to transfer this graph to jmeter - so that the load (threads) grows and falls.
Tell me, how can this be implemented in Jmeter?
I've tried using the Ultimate Thread Group and other thread groups from plugin, but everything looks too complicated there.
As a result, I want to get the same graph of the Thread Group after executing the script.
[my profile of load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACUgR.png)

I came across an implementation in [OctoPerf](https://api.octoperf.com/doc/runtime/edit-scenario/edit-user-profile/strategy/load/?_gl=1*1lfbr7c*_ga*MTkwMDUwNjg0MS4xNjc4NzIwOTUx*_ga_Q0Q7BY8NRR*MTY3ODgwMzcwNy4zLjEuMTY3ODgwNDcwMC4wLjAuMA..#load-table). But how to do it without external software?

[example from OctoPerf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXYga.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the possibility to define the workload model without **any** external software - take a look at [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group) available since [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

[image]

However if the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) is "too complicated" for you most probably you won't like the Open Model Thread Group as well.